# Re-create a "tree contains element" with foldback. I don't understand why it's working

Tags: f#, tree, fold

I was trying to recreate with a Foldback a function that given a tree and an element x, it will output true if the element is inside the tree, false instead.

This is my tree:

```
type 'a binTree =
  | Null                                     // empty tree
  | Node of 'a  * 'a binTree * 'a binTree
```

This is my code without the foldback

```
let rec containsTreeBis bTree y =
match bTree with 
    | Null -> false
    | Node(x,left,right) -> 
        match x=y with 
            | true -> true 
            | _ -> containsTreeBis left y || containsTreeBis right y
```

And this is my foldTree function which applies the fold to a tree:

```
let rec foldTree f e tree = 
match tree with
  | Null -> e
  | Node (x, left, right) ->
    f x ( foldTree f e left )  ( foldTree f e right )
```

They both are working pretty good.

Now to the problem.

I tried to use the foldTree to do the same thing.
I was really convinced and sure that this was the right code

```
 let containsTreeF bTree pred = 
    foldTree ( fun y vl vr -> pred y || vl || vr ) true bTree
```

but doing some checks with FsCheck, it turns out the result is Falsiable.

I randomly changed the code to this:

```
 let containsTreeF bTree pred = 
    foldTree ( fun y vl vr -> pred y || vl || vr ) false bTree
```

Changed the true at the end with false.

Did the FsCheck. It works.

How? I'm not getting it.

Comment: Nevermind, i understood the code right after posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fold` function is implemented correctly and so the question is about how to use the `fold` function to check whether a tree (or anything with a `fold` operation) contains a specified element.

To do this, you need to use `false` as the initial value and logical `or` as the operation, i.e:

```
let contains x tree = 
  foldTree (fun y vl vr -> x = y || vl || vr) false tree
```

This will return `false` for an empty tree. If either branch contains the element then `true || false` will be `true`, but if none of the brnaches contain it then `false || false` will result in `false`.

How come your FsCheck tests did not catch this when you had `true` as the initial value? With that initial value, your function will always return `true`, so you would catch this with a test that looks for an element that is not contained in a tree.

A unit test for that would be:

```
let t = Node(1, Node(2, Null, Null), Null)
contains 7 t
```

With FsCheck, you could generate tree with values from some randomly generated set and then check that it contains an item that is not in this set.